# Background mode phonegap in ios8

Tags: ios, cordova, background, stream

We are working on an ios phonegap app where we would like to add an alarm clock. We know that we have to activate the background mode options in the info.plist file and that the background service is restricted to 10 minutes life time in ios 8. We tried to extend the 10 minute range with several plugins but could not get it working. Our app is requesting data asynchronously from a web server and checks them against the data on the mobile device. If the the data is equal a radio stream should start. Do you have any idea how we could get this running?

Greetings
Alex